# How to change the color of another link on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the simple HTML code:

```
<li class="main">
<a href="#">ImageLink</a> <!--1st anchor tag-->
<a href="#">ImageName</a> <!--2nd anchor tag-->
</li>
```

Is it possible to change the color of 2nd anchor tag on hover state of 1st anchor tag? (And vice versa.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with css. This kind of actions can only be done by script.

If you use jQuery you could add the following script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var a1 = $('a:first');
            var a2 = $('a:second');

            a1.hover(function(){ a2.toggleClass('hover') }, function(){ a2.toggleClass('hover') });
            a2.hover(function(){ a1.toggleClass('hover') }, function(){ a1.toggleClass('hover') });

        });
</script>
```

Now you can use the hover class to specify the color:

```
.hover { color: red; }
```

**Edit**
It would be easier to give both `a`'s an id, so you could reference them by using `var a1 = $('#a1');`.

Comment: Slight error: `$(document).ready` not `read`. Can also be simplfied to `$(function() {`

Comment: Thanks. I always use `$(document).ready`, but I see `$(function() {` a lot. What are the arguments to choose one over the other?

Comment: I think it is purely used as shorthand. I suppose it is all personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

With CSS, it's possible to change the color of the 2nd anchor tag on hover of the 1st anchor tag with a sibling selector, but I don't think you can do it vice-versa:

```
a:hover + a {
    color: red;
}
```

JSFiddle preview: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ezt5/

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

However, note that adjacent sibling selectors are not supported on all browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: This Adjacent selector css is not supported by All browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with pure css.

for  example:

```
a:hover + a{
 background:red;
}
```

Check this for more

### http://jsfiddle.net/Bw5by/

Comment: But that does not do the vice-versa.

Comment: This Adjacent selector css is not supported by All browsers.

Comment: Cool. What browsers support this feature? And could I do it with the 3th or the 5th 'a' in a row?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker; for hit specific object you can use :nth-child pseudo element but it's not work in IE8 & below

Comment: @sandeep what about vice-versa thing?

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you can do it like this,

```
$("#first").hover(function(){
    $('#second').css('color','red')
    },function(){
    $('#second').css('color','blue')
    });
```

See it in action here,

http://jsfiddle.net/gagan/NYAHY/1/

Comment: If you want to change color of first on hover second. just replace 'first' with 'second'

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only two links in the list item tag, then you could do something like this:

```
li.main:hover a
{
    color: red;
}

li.main a:hover
{
    color: blue;
}
```

Then your hovered link will be blue, and all the other ones (in this case just that other one) will be red.