# JQuery Hover Function changes another

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254339/how-to-change-the-color-of-another-link-on-hover). I have the same anchor links with the same class names. My question is, how to do this that will not affect others when I try to hover the 'long-text' link? The image below shows that when I hover the anchor link below the upper will be affected too.

html

```
<a class="short-text">Short Text</a>
<a class="long-text">Long Text Here</a>

<a class="short-text">Short Text</a>
<a class="long-text">Long Text Here</a>
```

jquery

```
$(".long-text").hover(function(){
$('.short-text').css('color','orange')
},function(){
$('.short-text').css('color','black')
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method like following.

```js
$(".long-text").hover(function () {
    $(this).prev('.short-text').css('color', 'orange')
}, function () {
    $(this).prev('.short-text').css('color', 'black')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="short-text">Short Text</a>
<a class="long-text">Long Text Here</a>

<a class="short-text">Short Text</a>
<a class="long-text">Long Text Here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```js
$(".long-text").hover(function(){
$(this).prev().css('color','orange')
},function(){
$(this).prev().css('color','black')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="short-text">Short Text</a>
<a class="long-text">Long Text Here</a>

<a class="short-text">Short Text</a>
<a class="long-text">Long Text Here</a>
```